# Why unlist() convert a list of lists of strings into numbers?

Tags: r, list, text, nlp

I am doing text analysis in R. I have a list of lists that contain ngrams.

Look like this:

```
> list_tetragrams[459]
[[1]]
 [1] a small stage show          album of jazz standards     an album of jazz            and play small rooms       
 [5] and release an album        can translate into a        her late s and              i think she’ll wait        
 [9] in her late s               into a small stage          late s and release          maybe something she can    
[13] one can dream right         play small rooms jazz       release an album of         s and release an           
[17] she can translate into      she’ll wait until she’s     she’s in her late           show and play small
```

I want to convert this list of lists into one list. Here's what I did and the output:

```
Fngram<- list(unlist(unlist(list_tetragrams)))

Output:
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  1  2  3  1  1  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
  [39] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

The code I have been used multiple times, and it is the first time something like this happened. I have tried to use flatten() function or do.all() function. All return the same output. What happened? Can someone please figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: It is possible that you have `factor` class..  Why you are doing `unlist` twice.  By default `unlist` have `recursive = TRUE`.  Can you try `list(rapply(list_tetragrams, as.character))`

Comment: If a list or vector you're looking at is supposed (inferred to be strings but is lacking the `"` quotes, then it is almost certainly a `factor`. See `list(factor("a b"))` versus `list("a b")`. It appears that in your code snippet above, you omitted the output that lists `Levels: a small stage show album of jazz standards ...` (which is, imo, a poor representation in its own, as it uses space-delimited format for strings with embedded spaces).

Comment: akrun, it worked. It never happened before so I wasn't thinking of the data type. Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use a recursive function to convert the values to `character` from `factor` (the integer coercion values suggest that the nested list elements are `factor` class), by default, the `how = 'unlist'` in `rapply`), then we wrap those `vector` with `list` to create a single `list` element

```
list(rapply(list_tetragrams, as.character))
```